# Get List of Objects Added to Entity Framework 6 Include List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Background**

I have created object graphs in Entity Framework where any given object A will have a table Ac that tracks changes for it. These objects may also connect to each other, such as A being 1-many to B. Here is an example graph:

```
            A -> Ac
           /  \
    Bc <- B    \
         /      \  
  Cc <- C        D -> Dc
```

I want to be able to load an object and specific connected objects at a point in time by using the change tables to pull those records and apply them. Ideally, I'd like to be able to either use or mimic the `.Include` function from Entity Framework.

**The Issue**

Pulling out which objects are already included in an `IQueryable` is not as easy as I guessed it would be. Looking at an `IQueryable<T>` with a child object of T `Include()`-ed, I can see that these relationships are stored in some sort of `Span` object within an `Arguments` property - but these are both internal classes and trying to retrieve this information has a lot of steps.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static void LoadVersion<T>( this IQueryable<T> query, DateTime targetDateTime )
    {
        //grab the value of the "Arguments" property on query.Expression
        //this has to be done through reflection because "Arguments" is not accessible otherwise
        PropertyInfo argumentsPropertyInfo = query.Expression.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == "Arguments" );
        dynamic argumentsPropertyValue = argumentsPropertyInfo.GetValue( query.Expression );

        for (int i = 0; i < argumentsPropertyValue.Count; i++)
        {
            //This gets me a System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Span, but that class is internal  
            //In the watch, I can see span -> SpanList[0].Navigations[0] gives me the name of the class in the .Include()
            //      This is the value I need
            dynamic span = argumentsPropertyValue[i].Value;

            //So if I try to pull it out using the same reflection trick as before, I get
            //      a dynamic {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[0]} (not a list, as you would normally expect), 
            //      and accessing those values & methods makes the debugger exit without an exception
            dynamic spanPropertyInfo = argumentsPropertyValue[i].Value.GetType().GetProperties();

            //this makes the debugger exit without an exception
            dynamic spanPropertyValue = spanPropertyInfo[0].GetValue(span);

            //this also makes the debugger exit without an exception (with the above line commented out, of course)
            dynamic spanPropertyValue2 = spanPropertyInfo.GetValue( span );                
        }
    }
```

Based on how difficult it is for me to find what is Included in a Query, I can't help but think that I am doing this entirely the wrong way. Digging through some of the Entity Framework 6.1.3 source code hasn't shed much light on this.

## Edit

I've been playing around with the code provided by Alex Derck, but I realized I still need a few pieces to make this work the way I want.

Here is the version of `VisitMethodCall` I implemented:

```
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall( MethodCallExpression node )
{
    if (node.Method.Name != "Include" && node.Method.Name != "IncludeSpan") return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

    try
    {
        string includedObjectName = (string) node.Arguments.First().GetPrivatePropertyValue( "Value" );

        if (includedObjectName != null)
        {
            _includes.Add(includedObjectName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e ){ }
    return base.VisitMethodCall( node );
}
```

I'm able to construct a query with includes and get the names of the objects I included using the IncludeVisitor, but the main goal to use these was to be able to find the related tables and add them to the include.

So when I have the equivalent of this:

```
var query = ctx.Persons.Include(p => p.Parents).Include(p => p.Children);
// includes[0] = "Parents"
// includes[1] = "Children"
var includes = IncludeVisitor.GetIncludes(query.Expression);
```

I am successfully grabbing the `includes`, and I can then find the related tables (Parents -> ParentsChanges, Children -> ChildrenChanges), but I'm not 100% sure how to add these back to the include.

The main problem here is when it's a nested statement:
`context.A.Include(x => x.B).Include(x => x.C).Include(x => x.B.Select(y => y.D))`

I can successfully traverse that whole graph and get the names of A, B, C, and D, but I need to be able to add a statement like this *back to the include*:

`[...].Include(x => x.B.Select(y => y.D.Select(z => z.DChanges)))`

I can *find* DChanges just fine, but I don't know how to build that include back up because I don't know how many steps are between DChanges and the original item (A).

Comment: Do your entities implement an interface (or inherit from a base class) so you know how to get to their change tracking tables?

Comment: Yeah, I have ways to find their change tracking tables once I have the class.

Comment: Looking again at your question I wonder: why don't you just attach the objects in your object graph and then apply the changes (and set Added or Deleted state). You don't have to load the objects first. If I understand you correctly you have some sort of self-tracking entities, so they carry all required information to feed EF's change tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Alex, I was able to get what I wanted.

First, to get the name of the includes, I used a small variation of one of the earlier versions of the answer Alex posted:

```
internal static class IncludeVisitorExtensions
{
    public static object GetPrivatePropertyValue( this object obj, string propName )
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty( propName, BindingFlags.Public
                                        | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );
        return propertyInfo.GetValue( obj, null );
    }

    public static object GetPrivateFieldValue( this object obj, string fieldName )
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField( fieldName, BindingFlags.Public
                                     | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );
        return fieldInfo?.GetValue( obj );
    }
}

internal class IncludeVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private static readonly IncludeVisitor Visitor;
    private static List<string> _includes;

    private IncludeVisitor() { }

    static IncludeVisitor()
    {
        Visitor = new IncludeVisitor();
    }

    public static ICollection<string> GetIncludes( Expression expr )
    {
        _includes = new List<string>();
        Visitor.Visit( expr );
        return _includes;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall( MethodCallExpression node )
    {
        if (node.Method.Name != "Include" && node.Method.Name != "IncludeSpan")
            return base.VisitMethodCall( node );

        //"Include" == .Where() is present in the query
        //"IncludeSpan" == no .Where() in the query

        try
        {
            if (node.Method.Name == "Include")
            {
                string includedObjectName = (string) node.Arguments.First().GetPrivatePropertyValue("Value");

                if (includedObjectName != null)
                {
                    _includes.Add(includedObjectName);
                }
            }
            else if (node.Method.Name == "IncludeSpan")
            {
                var spanList =
                    node.Arguments.First().GetPrivatePropertyValue("Value").GetPrivatePropertyValue("SpanList");

                var navigations = ((IEnumerable<object>) spanList).Select(s => s.GetPrivateFieldValue("Navigations"));

                foreach (var nav in navigations)
                    _includes.Add(string.Join(".", (IEnumerable<string>) nav));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return base.VisitMethodCall( node );
    }
}
```

One little detail I found when testing his code is the difference in how the included tables are found in the expression based on the presence of a `.Where()` in the `IQueryable<>`. Thankfully, this can be checked based on the method name, and while the code is a bit ugly, it does dance around the vastly different structures to return the correct name of the table.

Now I have the *name* of the table, pluralized, as a string. This is because the name is from the `DbContext`, so I can reflect over the properties and get the *Type* of the table:

```
List<PropertyInfo> contextProperties = typeof( TContext ).GetProperties().ToList();
PropertyInfo prop = contextProperties.First( x => x.Name == s );
```

With the Type, I can accurately find the table I need via Navigation Properties, then I can build a `string` to send into my new .Include:

```
ICollection<string> includes = IncludeVisitor.GetIncludes( query.Expression ); 

foreach (string include in includes)
{
    //sometimes the returned include string will be two tables joined with a '.'; these need to be split and each one checked independently
    List<string> split = include.Split( '.' ).ToList();

    foreach (string s in split)
    {
        //using .First here because we expect the property to exist
        PropertyInfo prop = contextProperties.First( x => x.Name == s );                    

        //the property will be of type DbSet<ObjectType>, so grab the first generic argument (in this case, the object type)
        Type dbSetPropertyType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();

        //Get the type we're looking to add in the .Include
        var targetTable = GetTargetTableBasedOnTypeViaNavigation(dbSetPropertyType);                 

        //get the name of the property based on the type of the table we just looked up
        PropertyInfo contextProperty = contextProperties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType && x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First().Name == targetTable.Name );

        string includeString = "";                    

        //build the string and add it to the query
        includeString += include + "." + contextPropertyForChangeTracker.Name;
        query = query.Include(includeString);        
    }
}
```

This worked on my initial test data sets, though I'm not sure how well it will handle more complex graphs.

Answer (score 1):

After looking a bit in the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) of Entity Framework I noticed the includes are not part of the `Expression`, but rather part of the `IQueryable`. If you think about it, it's pretty obvious it should be that way. Expressions can't actually execute code themselves, they are translated by a provider (which is also part of the `IQueryable`), and not all providers should know how to translate an `Include` method. In the source code you can see the `IQueryable.Include` method calls the following small method:

```
public ObjectQuery<T> Include(string path)
{
    Check.NotEmpty(path, "path");
    return new ObjectQuery<T>(QueryState.Include(this, path));
}
```

The query (casted to an `ObjectQuery`) simply gets returned and only it's internal `QueryState` gets changed, nothing at all happens to the expression. In the debugger you can see the EntitySets that will be included if you look in the `IQueryable`, but I haven't been able to put them into a list (`_cachedPlan` is always null when I try to access it through reflection).

[image]

I think after seeing this, the thing you're trying to do is not possible, so I would keep a static list of strings in my dbContext and implement a custom `Include` extension method:

```
public partial class TestDB
{
    public static ICollection<Expression> Includes { get; set; } = new List<Expression>();

    public TestDB() : base()
    {
        Includes = new List<Expression>();
    }

    ...
}

public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> CustomInclude<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<T,TProperty>> include) where T : class
    {
        TestDB.Includes.Add(include);

        return query.Include(include);
    }
}
```

You could also 'override' the normal `Include` method from `System.Data.Entity`. 
I say 'override', because technically it's not really possible to override an extension method, but you can just create an extension method called `Include` with the same parameters yourself, and if you don't include `System.Data.Entity` where you use it, there's no ambiguity between your own method and the one from `System.Data.Entity`:

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<T,TProperty>> include) where T : class
    {
        TestDB.Includes.Add(include);

        var method = typeof(QueryableExtensions)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Include")
            .First(m => m.GetParameters().All(p => p.ParameterType.IsGenericType));
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(TProperty));

        return (IQueryable<T>)generic.Invoke(query, new object[] { query, include });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey this was extremely helpful. I'm a little unclear on the part where you try to grab the value of SpanList, as that property doesn't seem to show up on the Node. This makes the part where you try to grab the Navigations not work well, and it appears that the string out of Value is what you were trying to find the whole time. I updated the original question with a little more info, so if you could take a look that'd be awesome.

Comment: @Max Changed the line, so the nested properties get concatenaded with a `.` like in EF. Can you check if your expression tree looks differently, added a screenshot at the bottom?

Comment: Your node.Arguments[0] is of type SpanList, while mine is of type ConstantExpression. The only difference between our LINQ statements that build the query is that the one I'm using to test this code has a `.Where(x => x.Id == MyTestId)` in it.

Comment: @Max Yes, but a `Where` clause shouldn't get past the `node.Method.Name == "Include" || node.Method.Name == "IncludeSpan"` check. Seeing your edit you say you've been able to get the names of the separate properties. Did you see my edit with the `String.Join`? The strings that gives back should be correct for the include if I'm not mistaken. See [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696395(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: Here is my call: `context.A.Where( x => x.Id == 1234).Include( x => x.B)`. When I look at `node.Arguments[0].Value`, I get "B". If I change this test code to `context.A.Include( x => x.B)`, then `node.Arguments[0].Value` is a `Span`. If you change your test query to have a `.Where( x => x.id = x.id)`, you should see the same results. That or some other issue is causing this to not work the way I expect locally - but I'm able to recreate this by adding or removing the .Where.

Comment: @Max I could indeed reproduce it, turns out the includes are part of the `IQueryable`, not of the `Expression` (see edited answer for possible workaround).

Comment: I am going to do some additional testing early next week, but I think I was actually able to get what I needed with the earlier versions of your answers. Thanks for the help - I'm going to give yours the bounty, as I couldn't have gotten there without the details you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I write here another answer to your question (but not the solution you need).

You can retrieve the objects added to entity framework 6 include list from an already retrieved entity in the same way the entity proxy does.

The property to retrieve if a property should be lazy loaded on access (so not already loaded and not in include list) is `Relationship.IsLoaded`. You can find the list of relationships in `YourEntityWithProxy._entityWrapper.Relationships`.

`_entityWrapper` and other properties are private so you need to use reflection to read them.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this instance the entity is not already loaded.